# Clojure: Require png-extract doesnt work with []'s?

Tags: clojure, require

Why does this work:

```
(ns image-test.core 
    (:gen-class) 
    (:require (png-extract) 
              [clojure.string :as string]))
```

but this fails:

```
(ns image-test.core 
     (:gen-class) 
     (:require [png-extract :as png] 
               [clojure.string :as string]))
```

I thought [] were always ok in require.  Please edify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(:require (png-extract))` is a no-op, "succeeding" by doing nothing. Using parens here means you're starting a prefix list, like `(:require (clojure set string))` to require `clojure.set` and `clojure.string`; since you don't put any namespaces after the `png-extract`, it's not requiring anything at all. Using `[]`s is correct, but it's failing because there's something wrong with the `png-extract` namespace: perhaps it doesn't exist, or is broken in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using both forms:

```
image-test.core> (ns image-test.core
                  (:gen-class)
                  (require [clojure.string :as foo ] 
                           [clojure.string :as string]))
nil
image-test.core> (ns image-test.core
                  (:gen-class)
                  (require (clojure.string)
                           [clojure.string :as string]))
```

Perhaps something with the png-extract dependency?

Comment: It sounds like it, I couldnt find the source of it on github nor docs, so I suspect its not fully built out, though it is on clojars.  thanks for having a look!